# make a list of infos adding Id in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to make list of infos inputing Name, Work. THere is a form with those inputs. Putting Name and Work when SAVE button clicked, it will add to the list. and view them. But I also want to add id every time. How can I do this?

here is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/VDYYrxk8Bz5KIoI0HFV4?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller='MyController'>

    <!-- <button ng-click='toggleForm()'>Upload</button> -->

    <div>
        <table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Work</th>
            </tr>
            <tr  ng-repeat='info in infos'>
                <td>{{info.name}}</td>
                <td>{{info.work}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <form class='form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input class='form-control' type="text" ng-model='info.name'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Work</label>
            <input class='form-control' type="text" ng-model='info.work'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='addInfos()'>Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

script::

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('MyController', function($scope){

    // $scope.displayForm = false;
    // $scope.toggleForm = function(){
    //     $scope.displayForm = !$scope.displayForm;
    // };
    $scope.infos = [];
    // var currIndex = 0;
    $scope.addInfos = function () {
        $scope.infos.push({
            name: '',
            work: ''
            // id: currIndex++
        });
        // $scope.infos.push(obj.info);

    };
})
```

Comment: For starters, your plunkr is bringing in the Angular 2 library, but you're creating an Angular 1 app. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.addInfos = function () {
        $scope.infos.push({
            name: $scope.info.name,
            work: $scope.info.work,
            id: $scope.infos.length + 1 // assuming you want ids to start with 1
        });   
        $scope.info = {}; // to clear the form fields once an input is pushed to the array
    };
```